# Regex. Test to validate alphanumeric string with one or two characters

Tags: regex, string

I can´t get this right. I need to validate a string with 1 or 2 alphanumerical characters in. If either of the characters is non- alphanumerical, the test should fail. With the tests, I have done so fare I got the result,

- If the sting is 1 character long – no problem. Working.
- If the sting is 2 character long and the string begins with a non- alphanumerical character – no problem. Working.
- If the sting is 2 character long and the string begins with a alphanumerical character follow by a non-alphanumerical character – I got problems.

How do you get regex. to fail the hole test when the sting can be 1 **or** 2 character long.

Anyone have some idea how to solve this?

Comment: where is the regex??

Comment: @Peter: `^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$`, or `^\p{L}{1,2}$` or `^[[:alpha:]]{1,2}$` - please let know which one works for you so that I could answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[[:alnum:]]{1,2}$
```

[Online demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/uG8iE6/1)

The regex matches strings consisting of 1 or 2 alphanumeric characters only. Here `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a string, `[[:alnum:]]` matches alphanumeric characters, and `{1,2}` is a quantifier (one or two characters).